# Laravel model pass to view

Tags: php, laravel, wizard

Im using this library: https://www.laravelplay.com/packages/ycs77::laravel-wizard

I did all steps and have the same result like in the example.

Im trying to get data from database to each step.

Model (*App/steps/intro/DropboxStep.php*):

```
<?php

namespace App\Steps\Intro;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Ycs77\LaravelWizard\Step;

use DB;

class DropboxStep extends Step
{
    /**
     * The step slug.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $slug = 'dropbox';

    /**
     * The step show label text.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $label = 'Dropbox';

    /**
     * The step form view path.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $view = 'steps.intro.dropbox';

    /**
     * Set the step model instance or the relationships instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation|null
     */
    public function model(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Save this step form data.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  array|null  $data
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation|null  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function saveData(Request $request, $data = null, $model = null)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Validation rules.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getOptions()
    {

        $stepa2 = DB::table('tutorials')->where('id', '2')->first();

        return [
            'stepa2' => $stepa2,
            'Lucas',
        ];
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ $stepa2 }}
</div>
```

Result:
Undefined variable: stepa2

Tried also through controller (IntroWizardController.php)

This is default controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Steps\Intro\DropboxStep;
use App\Steps\Intro\H2NStep;
use App\Steps\Intro\PT4Step;
use Ycs77\LaravelWizard\Wizardable;
use DB;



class IntroWizardController extends Controller
{
    use Wizardable;

    /**
     * The wizard name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $wizardName = 'intro';

    /**
     * The wizard title.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $wizardTitle = 'Intro';

    /**
     * The wizard options.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $wizardOptions = [];

    /**
     * The wizard steps instance.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $steps = [
        DropboxStep::class,
        H2NStep::class,
        PT4Step::class,
    ];

}
```

I added:

```
public function getOptions()
    {

        $stepa2 = DB::table('tutorials')->where('id', '2')->first();

        return [
            'stepa2' => $stepa2,
            'Lucas',
        ];
    }
```

Tried also in controller return to view, but then I get result from database in blank page, not with other parts.

Is it possible to pass database query to view with this library?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
With this routes:

```
Route::get('wizard/intro/dropbox', 'IntroWizardController@step1a', 'wizard.intro.dropbox');
Wizard::routes('wizard/intro', 'IntroWizardController', 'wizard.intro');
```

I get my result from database, but like I said before in white blank page:
[image: Blank page]

But I want to get in this view like others (without query):
[image: Steps]

Comment: with that getOptions() you get only that array ['stepa2', 'Lucas'] right?
And you want the view?

Comment: Its just from example. My goal is get result from database ( DB::table('tutorials')->where('id', '2')->first(); ) to view (each step has different blades)

Comment: OK, but do you want to just have a json when you hit that route or you want an actual html (blade.view)?

Comment: I want to pass to view.

Comment: Wizard::routes('wizard/intro', 'IntroWizardController', 'wizard.intro'); In web.php I have this route

Comment: @lewis4u updated question details with photos.

Comment: You can do this very easily by view share

Comment: @A.ANomancan you explain? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass any data from controller to blade view simply use these 2 options

option 1:

```
public function someFunction()
{
    $model = DB::table('model_table')->where('id', '2')->first();

    return view('blade_view_name', compact('model'));
}
```

option 2:

```
public function someFunction()
{
    $model = DB::table('model_table')->where('id', '2')->first();

    return view('blade_view_name')->with('model', $model);
}
```

if you have more or want more of variables you can chain the with() method like this:

```
return view('blade_view_name')
     ->with('model', $model)
     ->with('variable', 'Some other variable');
```

Comment: Yes... in that blade view you can show that variable from controller with {{ $variable }}